# Image hover on dissappear jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to make my image dissapear when i leave the button and appear when i go on it and here is my code, why isnt it working? I have included all the html and all of the file that we are using but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location:/LogIn/postlogin');
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

$('.button1').on('mouseover', function () {

             $("#image1").fadeIn(250);


          });

          $('.button1').on('mouseleave', function () {
             $("#image1").fadeOut(0);

          });
  $('.button4').on('mouseover', function () {

             $("#about").fadeIn(250);
        $("#frame").fadeIn(250);

          });

          $('.button4').on('mouseleave', function () {
             $("#about").fadeOut();
        $("#frame").fadeOut();

          });



</script>

    <title> Blue Bear </title>

    <meta name ="description" content = "kunal is a fag ;)">
    <meta name = "author" content = "Jason Bao and Kunal Desai(fag <3)">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css" type="text/css" />


    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
        <!-- /*<section id="menubar">

            <table>
            <ul id="main">
                <li><a href = "/">Home</a></li> 
                <li><a href = "/AboutUs">About Us</a></li>

            </ul>
            </table>

        </section>*/ --!>
        </header>
    <a class="button1" href="/home">Home</a>
    <a class="button2" href = "/signup">Join</a>    
    <a class="button3" href="/LogIn">Log In</a>
    <a class="button4" href = "/about">About Us</a>
    <a class="button12" href = "/about">About Us <br>
    <p id = "about" >co-Founders Kunal and Jason</p></a>
    <img id = "image1" border="0" src="../Images/1.png"  width="500" height="300"></img>
<img id = "image2" border="0" src="../Images/2.png"  width="500" height="300"></img>
<img id = "image3" border="0" src="../Images/1.png"  width="500" height="300"></img>
    <a id = "frame"></a>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: use `on` instead of `live`,As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: for some reason, that doesn't work either

Comment: also wrap the code within `$(document).ready(function(){ // your code here });` , in order to bind event after dom element is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.button1').mouseover(function () {

             $("#image1").fadeIn(250);


          });

          $('.button1').mouseout(function () {

             $("#image1").fadeOut(0);

          });
});
```

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/ZLsjv/